# Running jQuery code after page finishes loading AJAX content

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, ready

I have a page that loads content through AJAX. Among this content are some images. I need to do some formatting to the page layout depending on the images sizes (which vary) but in order to get the sizes, I need the images to finish loading first before running the code. If it was in an ordinary page (content loading normally WITHOUT AJAX), all I have to do is use the `$(window).load()` function but with AJAX it doesn't trigger for some reasons. I need a workaround to this : a way to execute some code after the images loaded through AJAX finish loading.

Basically, this is what I'm trying to do

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
//the responseText includes images among other information to be loaded 
$(window).load(function() {
...some code
});}}
```

but the `$(window).load()` never fires and I need to run the code once ALL images have finished loading so binding a load event to every image isn't really an option.

I have another question that is related and similar to the first one : the jQuery `$(document).ready` doesn't seem to fire either after content is loaded through AJAX. I don't need it right now but I will certainly do in the future, so any workarounds for this too ?

I would really appreciate your help and thanks a lot.

Comment: Bear in mind that $(element).load) **is** an AJAX request. <- Edit: I was wrong, ignore this comment

Comment: @Cranio  not quite true,  2 sets of docs for `load()` in API

Comment: i guess `$(window).bind('load',function)` would be the event you are looking for

Comment: @charlietfl Oh my bad, didn't know! Sorry to you and the OP and thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @KaiKönig Does that work (adapted) on a div instead of the window ?

Comment: @IlyesFerchiou Anyway, $(document).ready is fired when the "main" page has loaded, it has no relationship with AJAX. You must use a callback function.

Comment: @KaiKönig `bind('load',fn)` and `load(fn)` do the same in jQuery API  http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: The fact is there are two .load() functions in jQuery, one which fires an event when content has been loaded (DOM + images + ...) and one that is related to AJAX and sends a request to a page. Which one is executed depends on the arguments, the first one takes a function as an argument, the second one takes the url, data(querystring) and callback function as arguments. Placing my code in the callback function launches it before the content is fully loaded and rendered, placing my code within the "normal" .load() function which in its turn is within the AJAX .load() function doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(window).load works only for the page initial loading.

The only clean solution I see is counting the images (hoping they're the only problem) and waiting for them to load :

```
$('#results').load('youurl', function() {
    var $images = $('#contenu img');
    var count = $images.length;
    console.log('initial images count : ', count);
    var decrement = function() {
        if (--count==0) {
            console.log('All images loaded');
            // do something                 
        }
    };
    $images.each(function(){
       if (this.complete) {
           decrement();
       } else {
           this.onload = function(){
                decrement();
           };
       }
    });
});
```

This is now testable on [this site](http://dystroy.org/re7210/index.html?file=shooter.html) : click a link for a recipe and look at the console.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, this function does actually make all the code much shorter and easier. I'm new to AJAX, this is why I used the first thing I found which was the XMLHttpRequest. However, even though this function made things easier, my code, when placed in the callback function, launches immediately after the query is processed and NOT after all data has been loaded and images rendered. So basically, my code runs but can't get the images sizes since it runs before the images finish loading so now my code is shorter but I still have the same issue.

Comment: You're right. I've put a new (tested) version. But this is not generic and works only for images. You would have to extend it for more complex cases.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking of, but since I know there are some issues with the .load() function used with images, I wanted to avoid it. At least it works with the latest versions of IE,FF and Chrome. If any problems arise with other browsers or earlier versions, I'll deal with it. Thank you a lot for writing the code for me, you just made my life easier twice today. And I learned two new things, the AJAX load function and (even though obvious I guess) : that you can make an operation "--count" here, within a condition check. I'm a mechanical engineer so... And best answer it is.

Comment: Well, actually it works. But before, in other websites, I was trying to bind a load() event to images and I noticed in some cases (some old versions or some specific cases) it doesn't work. It is a well know issue, you can read about it in the "Caveats of the load event when used with images" section of this [website](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you want is the [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) plugin. After loading the markup via AJAX, select the images inside this div and call `.imagesLoaded()` on them:

```
$('.article img').imagesLoaded( myCallbackFunction );
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, but this is a workaround for cashed images, this is not my case. My code doesn't trigger even when the images are NOT cashed. And in this case I'm dealing with images, but in general, when I have a code to run after that certain data inserted through AJAX has completely rendered, I want to know how I can make it run.

Comment: This one works. Needed to execute js after image requests from ajax response are done loading, and this plugin does just that

Answer (score 0):

Besides, you use the XMLHttpRequest... it's much easier with JQuery. You can get rid of all the code you posted and simply do:

```
$("#results").load("ajaxpage.php", function() { ... some code... });
```

Is all that you need. If you need to fire some code when the window is loaded, use your $(window).load().
If you need to fire the code after the ajax request, just put it in the callback function() above

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, but as I said to dystroy, placing my code in the callback function makes it run immediately after the query is processed and NOT after all data has been loaded and images rendered. So basically, my code runs but can't get the images sizes since it runs before the images finish loading so now my code is shorter but I still have the same issue.